# "'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in position 510335: character maps to <undefined>" when loading a csv in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab, altair

I am running this code in Jupyter Lab and I get the following error. I can't figure out what the problem is. I am using Altair/Pandas on Jupyter Lab to visualise the Pleiades dataset.

```
import altair as alt
import altair_viewer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from vega_datasets import data

alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()

alt.data_transformers.enable('csv')
location_data = pd.read_csv("pleiades-locations2.csv")
location_data.head()

alt.Chart(location_data).mark_point().encode(
    x='reprLat:Q',
    y='reprLong:Q',
    color='timePeriods:N',
    tooltip='featureType')
```

If anyone knows where the issue might be, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: Apparently, the problem had to do with the way Windows reads Unicode, because I tried to run this on a Linux machine, and it worked fine.

Comment: What happens if I replace [this character](https://graphemica.com/%C5%9F) with another character and run it?

Comment: Did the comment above fix your issue @pab6750?